# Mustard CSS - Hamburger issue

Tags: html, css, mustard-ui

I am using the mustard css framework but I am having an issue when resizing my browser. The navigation bar is supposed to drop into a hamburger, the appears but when i click it nothing appears within it. I copied and pasted the mustard exact nav bar but still doesn't work. Am i missing something else I have to link.

My Navigation Bar

```
<nav class="mynav">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <div>
          <img class="mylogo" src="imgs/abs.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <a class="myfont" href="index.php">Abs'olute Fitness</a>
      </div>

      <a class="mobile-menu-toggle"></a>
      <ul class="mobile-menu menu">
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>
```

Mustard Navigation Bar

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-logo">
            <a href="/">mustard</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a class="active" href="/docs/installation">Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/kylelogue/mustard-ui" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="mobile-menu-toggle"></a>
        <ul class="mobile-menu menu">
            <li><a href="/docs/installation">Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/kylelogue/mustard-ui" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: show what you have done in form a of a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i posted my nav bar and the example nav bar from mustard

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript to toggle appearance. There's jquery example in repository, I'm using vanilla JS for that:

```js
    const hide = ((elem) => {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    });
    const show = ((elem) => {
      elem.style.display = 'block';
    });
    const toggle = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-toggle');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');
    toggle.addEventListener('click', ((e) => {
      if (menu.style.display !== 'block') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();  
        show(menu);
      }
    }));
    document.body.addEventListener('click', ((e) => {
      if (menu.style.display === 'block') {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();  
        hide(menu);
      }
    }));
```